# Split char* to char * Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, split

I'm trying to split a char* to an array of char* in C.
I'm used to program in Java / PHP OO. I know several easy way to do that in these languages but in C... I'm totally lost. I often have segfault for hours x)

I'm using TinyXML and getting info from XML File.

Here's the struct where we find the array.

```
const int MAX_GATES = 64;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *firstname;
    char *date;
    char *id;
    char *gates[MAX_GATES];
} UserInfos;
```

And here's where I fill this struct :

```
    UserInfos * infos = (UserInfos*)malloc(1024);

    infos->firstname = (char*)malloc(256);
    infos->name = (char*)malloc(128);
    infos->id = (char*)malloc(128);
    infos->date = (char*)malloc(128);

    sprintf(infos->firstname, "%s", card->FirstChild("firstname")->FirstChild()->Value());
    sprintf(infos->name, "%s", card->FirstChild("name")->FirstChild()->Value());
    sprintf(infos->date, "%s", card->FirstChild("date")->FirstChild()->Value());
    sprintf(infos->id, "%s", card->FirstChild("filename")->FirstChild()->Value());

    ////////////////////////
    // Gates
    char * gates = (char*) card->FirstChild("gates")->FirstChild()->Value();

    //////////////////////////
```

The only problem is on 'gates'.
The input form XML looks like "gate1/gate2/gate3" or just blank sometimes.

I want gate1 to be in infos->gates[0] ; etc.
I want to be able to list the gates array afterwards..

I always have a segfault when I try.
Btw, I don't really now how to initialize this array of pointers. I always initialize all gates[i] to NULL but It seems that I've a segfault when I do 
    for(int i=0;i

Thanks for all.

It's OK when I've only pointers but when String(char*) / Arrays / Pointers are mixed.. I can't manage =P

I saw too that we can use something like 
    int *myArray = calloc(NbOfRows, NbOfRows*sizeof(int));
Why should we declare an array like that.. ? x)

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm used to program in Java / PHP OO". You'd probably want to stick with that, then. ;)

Comment: 1) Pick up a book on C; 2) please don't cast the result of `malloc()`. (Or just don't cast at all, period, unless you really understand why.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that people frequently have with XML is that they assume all the elements are available.  That's not always safe.  Thus this statement:

```
sprintf(infos->firstname, "%s", card->FirstChild("firstname")->FirstChild()->Value());
```

Isn't safe to do because you don't actually know if all of those
functions actually return valid objects.  You really need something
like the following (which is **not** optimized for speed, as I don't
know the tinyXML structure name being returned at each point and thus
am not storing the results once and am rather calling each function
multiple times:

```
if (card->FirstChild("firstname") &&
   card->FirstChild("firstname")->FirstChild()) {
   sprintf(infos->firstname, "%s", card->FirstChild("firstname")->FirstChild()->Value());
}
```

And then, to protect against buffer overflows from the data you should
really be doing:

```
if (card->FirstChild("firstname") &&
   card->FirstChild("firstname")->FirstChild()) {
   infos->firstname[sizeof(infos->firstname)-1] = '\0';
   snprintf(infos->firstname, sizeof(infos->firstname)-1, "%s", card->FirstChild("firstname")->FirstChild()->Value());
}
```

Don't you just love error handling?

As to your other question:

*I saw too that we can use something like int *myArray =
calloc(NbOfRows, NbOfRows*sizeof(int)); Why should we declare an array
like that.. ? x)*

`calloc` first initializes the resulting memory to 0, unlike malloc.
If you see above where I set the end of the buffer to '\0' (which is
actually 0), that's because malloc returns a buffer with potentially
random (non-zero) data in it.  calloc will first set the entire buffer
to all 0s first, which can be generally safer.

Comment: People should just learn about regular expressions instead of all this XML parser nonsense... ;-)

Comment: Ha!  Or use a language where it's safe to reference structures that may not exist, such as perl hash trees.