# How to split LPWSTR with multiple delimiters & return array of LPWSTR in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to split LPWSTR with multiple delimiters & return array of LPWSTR in c++. How to do it?
I tried to do from the following question: 
[How to split char pointer with multiple delimiters & return array of char pointers in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883316/how-to-split-char-pointer-with-multiple-delimiters-return-array-of-char-pointe)

But it prints ?? for each wstring. What's wrong with it?

can I do it as I tried follow? If so what's the mistake I made? If not how to do it?

```
std::vector<wstring> splitManyW(const wstring &original, const wstring &delimiters)
{
    std::wstringstream stream(original);
    std::wstring line;
    vector <wstring> wordVector;

    while (std::getline(stream, line)) 
    {
        std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
        while ((pos = line.find_first_of(delimiters, prev)) != std::wstring::npos)
        {
            if (pos > prev)
            {
                wstring toPush = line.substr(prev, pos-prev);
                //wstring toPushW = toWide(toPush);
                wordVector.push_back(toPush);
            }
            prev = pos + 1;
        }
        if (prev < line.length())
        {
            wstring toPush = line.substr(prev, std::wstring::npos);
            //wstring toPushW = toWide(toPush);
            wordVector.push_back(toPush);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< wordVector.size(); i++)
    {
        //cout << wordVector[i] << endl;
        wprintf(L"Event message string: %s\n", wordVector[i]);
    }
    return wordVector;
}

int main()
{
    wstring original = L"This:is\nmy:tst?why I hate";
    wstring separators = L":? \n";

    vector<wstring> results = splitManyW(original, separators);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `wordVector[i]` ===> `wordVector[i].c_str()` in your `wprintf` invoke.

Comment: std::vector<wstring> is not the same as an array of LPWSTR.

Comment: Clang actually tells you about this: *error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'value_type' (aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>') through variadic function; call will abort at runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]*

Comment: Before moving on, have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly accessing the `wchar_t*` exposed from `std::wstring` when you print your final tokens. Further, your output format specifier is incorrect. Per the `wprintf` documentation ([see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf)), in particular "If the **`l`** specifier is used, the argument must be a pointer to the initial element of an array of `wchar_t`.".

A few modifications and stripping out some redundancies gives the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::wstring;
using std::vector;

std::vector<wstring> splitManyW(const wstring &original, const wstring &delimiters)
{
    std::wstringstream stream(original);
    std::wstring line;
    vector <wstring> wordVector;

    while (std::getline(stream, line))
    {
        std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
        while ((pos = line.find_first_of(delimiters, prev)) != std::wstring::npos)
        {
            if (pos > prev)
                wordVector.emplace_back(line.substr(prev, pos-prev));

            prev = pos + 1;
        }

        if (prev < line.length())
            wordVector.emplace_back(line.substr(prev, std::wstring::npos));
    }

    return wordVector;
}

int main()
{
    wstring original = L"This:is\nmy:tst?why I hate";
    wstring separators = L":? \n";

    vector<wstring> results = splitManyW(original, separators);

    for (auto const& w : results)
        wprintf(L"Event message string: %ls\n", w.c_str());

    getchar();
}
```

**Output**

```
Event message string: This
Event message string: is
Event message string: my
Event message string: tst
Event message string: why
Event message string: I
Event message string: hate
```

Note: I would have preferred using formatted stream output using `operator <<`, but that is somewhat unrelated to your question.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should have executed it under a debugger. You would have seen immediately that your parsing is correct, so is your vector.

The problem is that you are trying to use to old C wprintf with format `%s` which expects a C string (a null terminated char array), and you pass a std::string which is a totally different object.

You can either :

- do it the C way, getting the C string contained by the std::string:

  ```
  wprintf(L"Event message string: %s\n", wordVector[i].c_str());
  ```
- do it the C++ way, using wcout:

  ```
  wcout << L"Event message string: " << wordVector[i] << std::endl;
  ```

But your return value is **not** an array of LPWSTR but a vector of std::string.

You should first allocate the array of pointers to char array, then individually allocate the char arrays, return that... and do not forget to free everything.

Answer (score -1):

LPWSTR is wchar_t*, so basically what you need is wcstok.